# ASP.NET Core 2 - Passing parameters (correlation ID) from controller action to Global Exception Handler middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-middleware

I am using a global exception handler referring to articles like https://code-maze.com/global-error-handling-aspnetcore/ (**Handling Errors Globally with the Built-In Middleware** section), and it is working great. However I still haven't found a way to pass a correlation ID from WebAPI controller action method to the global exception handler. When the exception is handled in the global exception handler, I want to log the correlation ID to the AppInsights. The correlation ID is later used to find out which sequences of event ended up throwing the exception.

I thought about just using Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId in the exception handler, but not sure if this can give me the correct correlation ID when many users are using the Web API at the same time. Different correlation ID's are assigned for different users in the action methods.

I have seen many other questions around global exception handler but haven't found about this specific case. Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can use `Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier` as the correlation id. That’s what the default error page uses.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @poke. The correlation ID for my case is being passed from the client app to the Web API and not it is not something that is auto generated on the Web API. In the global exception handler, I see that Activity.Current?.Id returns a random GUID.

Comment: It’s not random though; it’s the internal correlation id that is used for requests within ASP.NET Core. If you want to use a different correlation id, you should make sure to change the `TraceIdentifier` so that the same one is used for the whole request.